# PS4 on raspberry pi

Tags: operating-systems

I want to know if it is possible to add the PS4 operating system to raspberry pi. I haven't tried anything yet, but I have found the os files on the PS4's website.

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberry Pi cannot run the PS4's operating system, because of architectural and hardware incompatibilities. The PS4's OS (while based on a freely available Linux distro) requires proprietary hardware and expects certain peripherals, moreover, I don't believe that even the new pi4 meets the system requirements.

Comment: There is nothing about it on the internet, but I also don't understand why it cannot do that.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_4_system_software)

> The operating system is Orbis OS, based on FreeBSD 9.

Operating systems generally need to include low-level hardware drivers for each different type of hardware they need to work on. This includes hardware such as specific USB-interface ICs, specific graphics accellerators as well as the exact CPU chips etc being used. A USB interface IC from two different makers might each require a different low-level device driver in the operating system. Often the makers of such ICs work with operating system developers to create such drivers. So a general purpose OS like Linux will include drivers for a vast range of different ICs and devices etc - almost none of which will exist on your particular computer.

Even so, general purpose operating systems often discard support for less-popular architectures. For example, Windows NT ran on a variety of RISC processors including Alpha, MIPS, PA RISC, and PowerPC. Windows 10 doesn't.

Sony probably only source, develop, integrate and supply device-drivers for the specific hardware and ICs used in the PS4.

Additionaly much of the higher level software (we might loosely call these applications) is likely to use APIs only available in special proprietary Sony libraries and device-drivers. Such software may depend on specific characteristics of the hardware and not be usable at all on hardware with differing characteristics. An example might be a dependency on a specific screen resolution or range of resolutions and colour-depths, or the availability of some specific high-level graphics-acceleration provided in firmware.

So to port Orbis to the Broadcom chipsets used on the Raspberry Pi, you might need to spend months or years developing very low-level code for the operating system.